# wordpress gallery plugin shortcode does not work

Tags: wordpress, gallery, shortcode

i have one wordpress site, and i want to use gallery plugin. but the shortcode does not work for me. Here is the link: http://www.imaboy.cn/wp/?p=25

I found that all shortcode for post do not work after i modified the single.php. Does anyone know where should i not change to make the shortcode work? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. i found the solution. Because the shortcode is outside of the loop, so the way to make it work is . If you have better solution, please share it.